# Creating Meeting lotus Meeting using ICall

Tags: java, xpages, ical4j, lotus-notes

In a eclipse plugin for the Lotus Notes client I need to create a **meeting** in a user's mailfile. I have created successfully an **appointment** in my own mailfile using the NotesCalendar object. (see code below ). What I don't seem to get right is to create a meeting instead of an appointment. On the database level the difference is made by a field called appointmenttype which is set to 3 in the case of a meeting and 0 in the case of a appointment.

According to resources I found I need to add the xProperty "X-LOTUS-APPTTYPE" with a value of "3" to my Ical4j object but for some reason this is not being processed by the NotesCalendar.createEntry() method.

Does someone have any idea how to create a Meeting in a mailfile using the NotesCalendar notes classes and Ical4j?

(the reason I have added the xPages tag is that I hope someone in the xPages community ever has used the notescalendar objects before )

Code that creates an appointment:

```
    DateTime meetingStart =  new DateTime(c.getStartTime().getTime());
    DateTime meetingEnd = new DateTime(c.getEndTime().getTime());

    VEvent meeting = new VEvent(meetingStart, meetingEnd, c.getSubject());


    // Add chair

    Attendee chairAttendee = new Attendee(URI.create("mailto:j.somhorst@development.acuity.nl"));
    chairAttendee.getParameters().add(Role.CHAIR);

    // Add invitees

    for(User invitee : c.getUserParticipants()){
        Attendee attendee = new Attendee(URI.create("mailto:"+invitee.getEmail()));
        attendee.getParameters().add(Role.REQ_PARTICIPANT);
        meeting.getProperties().add(attendee);
    }

    // create calendar for ics export

    Calendar call = new Calendar();
    call.getProperties().add(new ProdId("-//Lotus Development Corporation//NONSGML Notes 9.0.1//EN_API_C"));

    call.getComponents().add(meeting);

    // notes specific fields

    meeting.getProperties().add(new XProperty("X-LOTUS-NOTESVERSION","2"));
    meeting.getProperties().add(new XProperty("X-LOTUS-APPTTYPE","3"));

    NotesCalendar notesCalendar = NotesUtil.getNotesCalendar(s);
    if(notesCalendar!=null){
        notesCalendar.setAutoSendNotices(false);
        NotesCalendarEntry entry = notesCalendar.createEntry(call.toString());
        String icallvalue = entry.read();
        System.out.println(icallvalue);

    }
```

Comment: Try to send a meeting invitation to a Gmail (or any other non-Notes email address) and check the message source. You should see what Notes sends and it should help you to reproduce it backwards.

Comment: I have already found why it didn't work correctly. According to this: www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21631528 you need to add a organizer attendee. If that property is present Notes will handle the icall as a meeting object. Sounds logical to me